# ASP.NET 2 projects to share same files

Tags: asp.net

Well as the title says i have 2 web projects that have the same css files, master page and some resource files, how could i share those? atm i have 2 copies of them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an article that describes how to share pages and user controls between applications : [HOW TO: Share ASP.NET Pages and User Controls Between Applications by Using Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/825996). It's solution depends on separate virtual directory that holds the shared files.

And in [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/28/423888.aspx) Scott Guthrie describes how to build reusable web assemblies. It's solution depends on making separate assembly by shared files.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**: bind them into separate assemblies in share it across your projects.

**Reference**:

- [Building Re-Usable ASP.NET User Control and Page Libraries with Visual Studio 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479564.aspx)
- [How to embed resources in ASP.NET 2.0 assemblies](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910445)

Comment: sounds easy but how do you bind a css file in a seperate assembly? i got my resource file now in a seperate assembly and im using "PublicResXFileCodeGenerator" as build tool..

Comment: You could have a seporate library project which will be shared in all your website projects. Which will contain CSS files as resources.

Answer (score 1):

In the second project choose "Add existing file", select the file, click on the arrow on the add button and select "add as link".

Comment: Probably won't work for debugging, you'll need to publish to link the files in.

Comment: ok this does not seem to work at all the files are not added to the build output..

Comment: It does work; check the properties for the file.  Make sure its set to copy always to the output.

Comment: Copy to output will put the static files in subfolders of the /bin (i.e. the project build output) directory - not what you'd want.