# ASP.NET MVC: How can I add views, scripts and content files as links in order to share across projects? (Via "Add as Link" in VS)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, file, asp.net-mvc-3

I've got a common Layout.cshtml file that I want to share. When I add the file as a link in the project (via Add Existing Item > Add as Link) I get an error that it cannot be found when I run the application. If I set the build action to "Copy Always" it does copy the file to the build directory, however I still get an error that it cannot find the file (Perhaps I can somehow instruct VS to copy it to the appropriate directory?).

I came across this question: [ASP.NET 2 projects to share same files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684987/asp-net-2-projects-to-share-same-files) however the answers are pretty complicated and ugly and right now I'm playing around with a lot of different structures and refactoring methods so I don't want to go through some big production just to move a few different files around.

So how can I easily share these kinds of files between the two applications?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug in msbuild or an unsupported feature. Either way I finally found a workaround published on this guy's blog:

http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamesdawson/archive/2008/06/03/using-linked-files-with-web-application-projects.aspx

Comment: Instead of overriding the "_CopyWebApplication" target like the blog post says to do in step one of his workaround, I just skipped that step, applied the second step, and set "Copy to Output Directory" on the linked file to "Do not copy."

Comment: The link seems to be broken

Comment: This blog seems to work: http://ignew.com/2013/04/08/using-linked-files-in-asp-net-applications/ (includes support for both "Build" and "Clean" )

Answer (score 1):

You cannot *Add as Link* static files in an ASP.NET web application. All files need to be included inside this application or when you deploy it in IIS simply won't be able to find any of them. A common technique of sharing static files between multiple web applications is using CDN (Content Delivery Network) where you would host all your static resources (images, CSS, js, ...). For example [Google already provides](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html) popular frameworks on their CDN.

So for all your custom images you could setup a domain on your web server which will host them all and your web applications will point to this common location. Another advantage of this technique is that clients visiting those applications will already have all static resources in cache.

Comment: CDN's are great for stuff like libraries that probably aren't going to change during development very much, but it becomes a bear to work with files that will be changing quite a bit during development. You have to publish the files to your CDN each time before launching into debug mode. There HAS to be a better way than a CDN or NuGet package - I know this is an old answer, but it's the same suggestion I'm finding everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Someone else might give you a better solution, but my approach would be to:

```
 1 - Create a library project
 2 - Create a Resources file in the library project
 3 - Add the shared resources to the library project.
 4 - Compile the library project
 5 - Reference the DLL for the library project in the dependent projects
```

Comment: Views are *not* picked up from libraries by default. This will not help as the question asked includes Views.