# How to share cshtml pages across multiple projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, razor

I have a couple of pages common across all my ASP.NET projects. I would like to centralize that code inside a single assembly. How can I achieve this? Is it possible to simply create and assembly and add it as a reference of my ASP.NET projects and the pages are going to be accessible?

Comment: Possible duplicate. You can achieve the same result for cshtml files etc. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116465/how-do-you-share-code-between-projects-solutions-in-visual-studio

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I am not trying to link code. I want a shared library for ASP.NET pages.

Comment: Did you read the second answer about linking files? Also asnwered here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136128/asp-net-mvc-how-can-i-add-views-scripts-and-content-files-as-links-in-order-to

Comment: Yes, I did. I need the code in its own library.

Comment: Did you manage to get closer to any solution on this?

I am experiencing the same needs. Third party needs to code content, so to avoid sharing the "root" code, it would be nice to have it all in a shared library for them to include.

Comment: Include the view as EmbeddedResource and use EmbededdedResourceVirtualPathProvider

Answer (score 4):

Using razor views from a different (so from outside the web project) is not supported out of the box. However there a tool to precompile razor views and then you can put them in any dll. This custom tool is called [RazorGenerator](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/).

There are some blog posts where you can start:

[Precompile your MVC Razor views using RazorGenerator](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/06/precompile-your-mvc-views-using.html)
[Compile your asp.net mvc Razor views into a seperate dll](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/)